# ¿Cómo ocultar el ActionBar en Android?

Tags: java, android

Lo hice así pero no se oculta.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Comment: Aleks, he agregado una respuesta, pero me gustaría saber si usas clases de la librería de soporte.

Answer (score 7):

Debes asegurar ejecutar `getActionBar().hide()` después de `setContentView()`

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
getActionBar().hide();
```

si usas la librería de soporte sería:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Otro método se realiza mediante el tema `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar` asignado a tu Actividad, por ejemplo:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
</activity>
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta pero la lo había intentado también así con el xml. Estoy con la api 22.

Answer (score 4):

En mi opinión a tu pregunta le falta información. Si lo que deseas es ocultar el ActionBar después de haberlo mostrado entonces tienes que llamar al método hide.

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Y para ocultarla deberás llamar al método hide().

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Si lo que deseas es nunca mostrar la action bar entonces no la declares en el xml y nunca llames al método setSupportActionBar(mToolbar). Esto funcionará si estás utilizando el tema sin ActionBar de la librería de soporte.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 3):

A mi lo único que me ha funcionado  es poner en styles.xml

```
<resources>
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  </style>
</resources>
```

También puedes revizar este tutorial
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Defining-The-ActionBar

Answer (score 1):

¿Y si creas un estilo?

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Después puedes usar el estilo en el tema de tu actividad:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" ... />
```

También intentan esto:

```
 <activity>android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

....
>